# How to copy MongoDb database using C# driver when Authentication is enabled

Tags: c#, mongodb

In this post [Copy mongo database using C# driver][1] is described a solution to copy database with new Mongo C# driver.

I've a problem with authentication, I've setup authorization in mongodb, now if I issue a copydatabase from RoboMongo everything is ok, but if I try to run the command from C# Driver I get

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command copydb failed: 
listCollections failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "not authorized on xxxxx 
to execute command { listCollections: 1, filter: {}, cursor: {} }", 
code: 13 }.'
```

I wonder why the copy database command works with the same user in RoboMongo but fails with authorization when executed by C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've found the reason and it is pretty weird, you just need to remove the fromDb parameter from the command.

```
var command = String.Format(@"{{ copydb: 1, fromdb: '{0}', todb: '{1}'}}", sourceUrl.DatabaseName, destinationUrl.DatabaseName);
```

I've used the above command, where I only specify fromDb and toDb and everything went ok. Probably the fromDb: 'localhost' for some reason messed up with authentication.

Gian Maria.